# How can I make 2-way ANOVA (Type I, II and III) with R?

Tags: r, anova, sums-of-squares

I have the following data with factor 1 (A, B and C) and factor 2 (D and E):
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\hline
 & D & E\\
\hline
A & 68 & 59\\
 & 65 & 57\\
 & 63 & 54\\
 & 59 & 56\\
 & 67 & \\
\hline
B & 59 & 51\\
 & 50 & 45\\
 & 51 & 46\\
 &    & 48\\
 &    & 49\\
\hline
C & 40 & 47\\
 & 39 & 39\\
 & 35 & 40\\
 & 36 & 40
\end{array}
$$

Now I would like to make two-way ANOVAs of type I, II and III with R and interpret them.

I made the following:

```
rm(list=ls(all=T))
data <- c(68,65,63,59,67,59,50,51,40,39,35,36,59,57,54,56,51,45,46,48,49,47,39,40,40)
f1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2) ### A=0,B=1,C=2
f2 <- c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4) ### D=3,E=4
summary(aov(data ~ f1*f2)) ### type 1
install.packages("car")
library(car)
Anova(lm(data~f1*f2),type=c("II")) ### type 2
Anova(lm(data~f1*f2),type=c("III")) ### type 3
```

---

For type 1 I get

```
#Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#f1           1 1941.9  1941.9 193.420 4.58e-12 ***
#f2           1   65.5    65.5   6.527  0.01845 *  
#f1:f2        1  145.9   145.9  14.537  0.00102 ** 
#Residuals   21  210.8    10.0                     
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

---

For type 2 I get

```
#Response: data
#           Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
#f1        1901.11  1 189.355 5.607e-12 ***
#f2          65.53  1   6.527  0.018450 *  
#f1:f2      145.95  1  14.537  0.001016 ** 
#Residuals  210.84 21                      
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

---

For type 3 I finally get

```
#Response: data
#             Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
#(Intercept) 1802.06  1 179.489 9.308e-12 ***
#f1           329.87  1  32.856 1.089e-05 ***
#f2           208.54  1  20.771 0.0001714 ***
#f1:f2        145.95  1  14.537 0.0010157 ** 
#Residuals    210.84 21                      
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Is that all right? How would you interpret these results?

Comment: The degrees of freedoms suggest that f1 is an interval scaled variable and not a factor with three levels. Is this intended or did you mean something like "lm(data~factor(f1) * factor(f2))"?

Comment: Do not understand what you mean... f1 is standing for a factor with the three levels A, B and C. I used A=0, B=1, C=2.

Comment: You should rather code A='A', B='B', etc., because now in your model your two categorical variables are handled like if they were numeric. This is what Michael means.